# Gogits do not start as docker container

Tags: docker, permission-denied, openssh, gogs

I have installed Gogits as a docker container. It was working fine, but I had to restart my server and now my gogs container does not start. When i run command

```
docker start -a gogs
```

I get those errors repeated:

```
s6-supervise gogs: fatal: unable to mkfifodir event: Permission denied
s6-supervise openssh: fatal: unable to mkfifodir event: Permission denied
s6-supervise gogs: fatal: unable to mkfifodir event: Permission denied
s6-supervise gogs: fatal: unable to mkfifodir event: Permission denied
s6-supervise openssh: fatal: unable to mkfifodir event: Permission denied
s6-supervise openssh: fatal: unable to mkfifodir event: Permission denied
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been fixed with pull-request [1758](https://github.com/gogits/gogs/pull/1758).
The latest gogs/gogs docker image works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look where are those directories in your containers and make sure permissions are correct.

Maybe this is a shared volume and your docker user can't write to this shared volume?